# how to listen to a change in a stream from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting data from this stream builder and showing it inside a stateful  widget.

```
 Widget chatRoomsLists() {
        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream:  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('chatrooms').orderBy("lastMessageSendTs", descending: true)
                .where("users", arrayContains:myUserName)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
    
                    return  ChatRoomListTile(ds['lastMessage'], ds.id,myUserName! );
    
                  }) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }) ;
      }
```

and showing it here

```
class ChatRoomListTile extends StatefulWidget {

  final String lastMessage , chatRoomId, myUsername;
  ChatRoomListTile(this.lastMessage, this.chatRoomId, this.myUsername,);

  @override
  _ChatRoomListTileState createState() => _ChatRoomListTileState();
}

class _ChatRoomListTileState extends State<ChatRoomListTile> {
  String profilePicUrl = 'https://miro.medium.com/max/875/0*H3jZONKqRuAAeHnG.jpg' , name = ''  ,username = "";



  getThisUserInfo() async {
    print('userinfo called');
     username = widget.chatRoomId.replaceAll(widget.myUsername, "").replaceAll("_", "");
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await DatabaseMethods().getUserInfo(username);
    // print("something bla bla ${querySnapshot.docs[0].id} ${querySnapshot.docs[0]["name"]}  ${querySnapshot.docs[0]["profileURL"]}");
    name = "${querySnapshot.docs[0]["name"]}";
    profilePicUrl = "${querySnapshot.docs[0]["profileURL"]}";
    setState(() {});

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getThisUserInfo();
    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('BUILDING IS CALLED');


    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('name is $username and ${widget.myUsername}');
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Chatting(username, widget.myUsername)));
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  child: Image.network(profilePicUrl,

                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 12),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      name,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 3),
                    SizedBox(width: 220,
                        child: Text(widget.lastMessage,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            child: Divider(thickness: 0.5 ,),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to call get this future  `getThisUserInfo` every time there is change in `widget.lastmessage` . How can i do that ?
When i am calling this future inside the build , It is getting called again and again non stop .So how can i only call this when there is a new message only ?

Comment: I would suggest you to review the construction of your builder and check the `snapshot().listen()` method. You can refer to this [similar issue](https://flutterforum.co/t/listen-to-changes-in-firestore/1924/4)

Comment: i used the as advised    but its still get updated if the function is called twice.                                                                                            `final up = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
StreamSubscription getUpdate() {
    return
    up.collection('chatrooms')
        .snapshots().listen((event) {
      event.docChanges.forEach((change) {
        return getThisUserInfo();
      });

    });
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to review the construction of your builder and check the `snapshot().listen()`  method, you can refer to this [similar issue](https://flutterforum.co/t/listen-to-changes-in-firestore/1924/4) for that.

To your follow-up question, it is hard to say what is causing this duplicated update, as it can be a number of things and nothing in your code indicates that, so that being said, I would think of some logic that allows you to check if the update you want to make already happened, perhaps spending a read, which is less expensive than a write.

Comment: i used another stream inside the class .